# Spring @Transactional DAO calls return same object

Tags: java, spring, duplicates, mybatis, transactional

We are using Spring and IBatis and I have discovered something interesting in the way a service method with @Transactional handles multiple DAO calls that return the same record.  Here is an example of a method that does not work.

```
@Transactional
public void processIndividualTrans(IndvTrans trans) {
Individual individual = individualDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(trans.getPartyId());       

individual.setFirstName(trans.getFirstName());
individual.setMiddleName(trans.getMiddleName());
individual.setLastName(trans.getLastName());

Individual oldIndvRecord = individualDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(trans.getPartyId());
individualHistoryDAO.insert(oldIndvRecord);

individualDAO.updateByPrimaryKey(individual);
}
```

The problem with the above method is that the 2nd execution of the line
    individualDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(trans.getPartyId())
returns the ***exact object*** returned from the first call.

This means that oldIndvRecord and individual are the same object, and the line
    individualHistoryDAO.insert(oldIndvRecord);
adds a row to the history table that contains the changes (which we do not want).

In order for it to work it must look like this.

```
@Transactional
public void processIndividualTrans(IndvTrans trans) {
Individual individual = individualDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(trans.getPartyId());       
individualHistoryDAO.insert(individual);

individual.setFirstName(trans.getFirstName());
individual.setMiddleName(trans.getMiddleName());
individual.setLastName(trans.getLastName());
individualDAO.updateByPrimaryKey(individual);
}
```

We wanted to write a service called updateIndividual that we could use for all updates of this table that would store a row in the IndividualHistory table before performing the update.

```
@Transactional
public void updateIndividual(Individual individual) {
Individual oldIndvRecord = individualDAO.selectByPrimaryKey(trans.getPartyId());
individualHistoryDAO.insert(oldIndvRecord);
individualDAO.updateByPrimaryKey(individual);
}
```

But it does not store the row as it was before the object changed. We can even explicitly instantiate different objects before the DAO calls and the second one becomes the same object as the first.

I have looked through the Spring documentation and cannot determine why this is happening.

Can anyone explain this?

Is there a setting that can allow the 2nd DAO call to return the database contents and not the previously returned object?

Comment: Can you post the code of individualDAO & individualHistoryDAO?

Comment: Right behavior and this is how it should be.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Hibernate as ORM and this behavior is perfectly described in the Hibernate documentation. In the [Transaction chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions):

> Through Session, which is also a transaction-scoped cache, Hibernate provides repeatable reads for lookup by identifier and entity queries and not reporting queries that return scalar values.

Same goes for [IBatis](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/getting-started.html)

> MyBatis uses two caches: a local cache and a second level cache. Each
> time a new session is created MyBatis creates a local cache and
> attaches it to the session. Any query executed within the session will
> be stored in the local cache so further executions of the same query
> with the same input parameters will not hit the database. The local
> cache is cleared upon update, commit, rollback and close.

Comment: Thank you all.  I appreciate the explanation.